# Null response upon casting deferred result spring

Tags: spring, aop

I have implemented a spring AOP which will get a deferred result upon invoke(). When I try to cast it to the custom response object I get a null.

```
Object response = mi.proceed();
//The response  object exist1
//org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult@c
CustomResponse customResponse = (CustomResponse) ((DeferredResult) response).getResult();
//customResponse is coming as null
```

Any suggestion

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? And what is `mi` there? Show us your pointcut and how you wrote the advice, please!

Comment: I am using spring 4.3.7. mi is MethodInvocation